# R leaflet creates geometric striations in some maps but not others

Tags: r, leaflet

I have been creating leaflet maps from raster files with discrete values. Leaflet creates smooth maps form some of the rasters, but in other there is a strange pattern of geometric striations across the map. All of the rasters were derived from one original raster. In addition, the source raster files used to create the leaflet maps do not have this strange pattern.

Below is the code:

This code chunk creates the 'expected' maps

```
f <- function(r) {
  ifelse(r <= 100, 50,
         ifelse(r >= 100 & r < 150, 20,
                    ifelse(r >= 150, 0, NA)))
}

r1 <- calc(r, fun = f)

writeRaster(r1, overwrite=TRUE, 'filePath/r1.tif')

r1 <- projectRasterForLeaflet(r1, method = 'ngb')

pal_r1 <- colorBin(SAGA_pal[[1]], values(r1), bins = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,115,120,150,180,200,220), na.color = "transparent", reverse=TRUE)

(ll_r1 <- leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
    addRasterImage(r1, colors=pal_r1, opacity=0.5) %>%
    addLegend(pal=pal_r1, values=values(r1), title="r1")
)
```

[link to r1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr9MI.jpg)

```
This code chunk creates the strange pattern:
f <- function(r) {
  ifelse(r <= 100,180,
         ifelse(r >= 100 & r < 150, 120,
                ifelse(r >= 150 & r < 200, 80,
                       ifelse(r >= 200 & r < 400, 50,
                              ifelse(r >= 400 & r < 800, 50,
                                     ifelse(r >= 800 & r < 1200, 30,
                                            ifelse(r >= 1200,0, NA)))))))
}

[![r1][1]][1]

r2 <- calc(r, fun = f)

writeRaster(r2, overwrite=TRUE, 'filePath/r2.tif')

r2data <- r2

r2data <- projectRasterForLeaflet(r2data, method = 'ngb')

pal_r2 <- colorBin(SAGA_pal[[1]], values(r2data), bins = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,115,120,150,180,200,220), na.color = "transparent", reverse=TRUE)

(ll_r2 <- leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
    addRasterImage(r2data, colors=pal_r2, opacity=0.5) %>%
    addLegend(pal=pal_r2, values=values(r2data), title="R2")
)
```

[image: r1]

[image: r2]

Comment: I'm struggling to see any strange patterns in this image, possibly because its quite low resolution. Can you re-upload a higher-resolution image?

Comment: Sorry, there is  2MB file size limit. I'll add the HTML files

Comment: Could not add the htlms, but changed the images for jpgs with increased resolution

Answer (score 1):

The error causing this problem was in the classification of the leaflet palette. In the original code color mapping was done using the colorBin function:

```
pal_r2 <- colorBin(SAGA_pal[[1]], values(r2data), bins = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,115,120,150,180,200,220), na.color = "transparent", reverse=TRUE)
```

colorBin is intended to be used on continuous numeric data. The data I was using discrete numeric data. I believe that as the data was discrete, leaflet was not able to process this data through continuous processes. This resulted in the patter that I saw. I changed the function to colorFunction (intended to be used for discrete data).

```
pal <- colorFactor(SAGA_pal[[1]], domain = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,115,120,150,180,200,220), ordered = FALSE,
                   na.color = "transparent", alpha = FALSE, reverse = TRUE)
```

This fixed the problem.